# xuggler maven dependency pom.xml file error

Tags: java, maven, xuggler

when i try to use xuggler maven dependencies in my java maven project getting error "Missing artifact xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.2 "
mentioned the pom.xml file please look at once

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ensis.mediguru</groupId>
<artifactId>eDoctor</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>eDoctor</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>

    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <servlet.api.version>3.1.0</servlet.api.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <fasterxml.jackson.core.version>2.5.3</fasterxml.jackson.core.version>
    <codehaus.jackson.version>1.9.13</codehaus.jackson.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.10</mysql.version>
   <!--  -<xuggler.version>0.16</xuggler.version>-->

</properties>


<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Farmework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- xuggler for generating thumbnail -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
          <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Loggers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MYSQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.13-b01</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>eDoctor</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

can nay one tell how to resolve this?

Comment: run `maven` with goals `clean install` that will definitely do!

Comment: no luck,still getting same error

Comment: are you using eclipse??

Comment: yes,i am using eclipse

Comment: i am updating the pom.xml file,please look at once

Comment: Try going to `.m2` folder on you machine and delete the folder `xuggle`. Next time when you run, use the command `mvn clean install -U`. This will try to download the jar once again. See if it works.

Comment: no luck,getting same error

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <url>http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

It adds an extra remote repository to be searched for if xuggle:xuggle-xuggler isn't found in maven central (remote repository)

Comment: Thanks, oddly enough this works but the documentation they give for the maven pom on their site doesnt

Answer (score 1):

you are very unlikely to find xuggler jar in public repositories. xuggler is dying out, means any active development is stopped. Better chance is to find any one who has build the xuggler matching your architecture x32 or x64 and then manually install to your local maven repository

something like

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\xuggle-xuggler-noarch-{version}.jar -DgroupId=xuggle
    -DartifactId=xuggle-xuggler-noarch -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

here is a one
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxugglexugglernoarch54jar.htm

Comment: i am adding xuggle-xuggler:jar to project build path,when i generate web application in to war build path jars are coming to war or not?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure no `firewall/antivirus` is preventing eclipse from connecting to internet.

Add this node to pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After that right click `project` -> `Run as`->`Maven clean`
it will clean project then
right click `project` -> `Run as`->`Maven install`

This was causing because There is no artifact in central repository of maven named with `xuggle`.

`OR` If this fails too.

Download the `xuggle-utils.jar` and use `maven:install` command to install it your local .m2 repo.

This will definately solve the issue.

Comment: first one is not working,in the second option how can i do in eclipse

Comment: `https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-utils` download project, import existing maven project, run as maven clean then run as maven install! It will do the miracle automatically!!

Comment: both are different project how can resolve error in my project

Comment: it will resolve the dependency of `xuggle-utils:jar:1.22` by automatically installing it your local .m2 repo

Comment: i am getting error Missing artifact xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.2

Comment: @arjun to solve this problem, you need to be familar with maven concepts... do you use a repository manager (nexus, artifactory, ...) in your environment? If this is the case,  your settings may prevent maven from searching in the repository MrArjun mentioned

Comment: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java repo is no longer functioning , xuggler recommends it build for yourself as it development has stopped